# How do I change the Icon when clicking on tabs?

Tags: jquery

Im having a smallish issue with some tabs, Im trying to change the icon to a minus icon when on it and a plus icon when not on it if thats make sense.

Ive got it to change to a minus button when you click it but it wont change back when you click on another tab.

```
$('ul.nav-tabs li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i.tabIcon').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    $('ul.nav-tabs li:not(active)').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
});
```

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which tab library are you using?

Comment: Can you share tab html?

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI tabs then there is an event fired when you change the tab. https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: Also the code can be shorter, use `.toggleClass(className, addOrRemove);`

Comment: You remove `fa-plus` and add `fa-minus` in both cases, so even if your selectors would work, you'd see  the same behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Came with theme theme not a plugin or external script :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to remove the minus symbol on all icons, replacing them with the `+` symbol, then add the minus symbol to only the icon of the `li` that has been clicked on:

```
//Store as variable outside the function so we don't have to keep looking them up each
// time any of the li is clicked.
var $tabIcons = $('ul.nav-tabs li i.tabIcon');
$('ul.nav-tabs li').click(function(){

    //remove - from all icons, add +.
    $tabIcons.removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');

    //remove + from this tab icon, add -.
    $(this).find('i.tabIcon').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvf9u/